# Web scraping for downloading images from NHTSA website (CIREN crash cases)

Tags: python, web-scraping, dataset, web-crawler

I am trying to download some images from NHTSA Crash Viewer (CIREN cases). An example of the case   https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass-CIREN/CaseForm.aspx?xsl=main.xsl&CaseID=99817
If I try to download a Front crash image then there is no file downloaded. I am using beautifulsoup4 and requests libraries. This code works for other websites.

The link of images are in the following format: https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass-CIREN/GetBinary.aspx?Image&ImageID=555004572&CaseID=555003071&Version=0

I have also tried the previous answers from SO but none solution works, Error obtained:
No response form server

Code used for web scraping

```
from bs4 import *
import requests as rq
import os

r2 = rq.get("https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass-CIREN/GetBinary.aspx?Image&ImageID=555004572&CaseID=555003071&Version=0")
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.text, "html.parser")

links = []

x = soup2.select('img[src^="https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov"]')

for img in x:
    links.append(img['src'])

os.mkdir('ciren_photos')
i=1

for index, img_link in enumerate(links):
    if i<=200:
        img_data = rq.get(img_link).content
        with open("ciren_photos\\"+str(index+1)+'.jpg', 'wb+') as f:
            f.write(img_data)
        i += 1
    else:
        f.close()
        break
```

Comment: This is a task that would require selenium, but luckily there is a shortcut. On the top of the page there is a "Text and Images Only" link that goes to a page like this one: https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass-CIREN/CaseForm.aspx?ViewText&CaseID=99817&xsl=textonly.xsl&websrc=true that contains all the images. You can select that link with `soup2.find('a', text='Text and Images Only')`. Also, that link and the image links are relative, so you'll have to use `urljoin()` to get the full url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a task that would require Selenium, but luckily there is a shortcut. On the top of the page there is a "Text and Images Only" link that goes to a page like this one: https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass-CIREN/CaseForm.aspx?ViewText&CaseID=99817&xsl=textonly.xsl&websrc=true that contains all the images and text content in one page. You can select that link with `soup.find('a', text='Text and Images Only')`.

That link and the image links are relative (links to the same site are usually relative links), so you'll have to use [`urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin) to get the full urls.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as rq
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url = 'https://crashviewer.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass-CIREN/CaseForm.aspx?xsl=main.xsl&CaseID=99817'

with rq.session() as s:
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

    url = urljoin(url, soup.find('a', text='Text and Images Only')['href'])
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

    links = [urljoin(url, i['src']) for i in soup.select('img[src^="GetBinary.aspx"]')]

    for link in links:
        content = s.get(link).content
        # write `content` to file
```

So, the site doesn't return valid pictures unless the request has valid cookies. There are two ways to get the cookies: either use cookies from a previous request or use a [`Sessiion`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) object. It's best to use a Session because it also handles the TCP connection and other parameters.

Comment: The images which are downloaded using the script are not in the proper format, the binary files are getting downloaded. Following is the script which I am using along with your answer.                                                    
`os.mkdir('ciren_photos')
i=1

for index, img_link in enumerate(links):
    if i<=200:
        img_data = rq.get(img_link).content
        with open("ciren_photos\\"+str(index+1)+'.jpg', 'wb+') as f:
            f.write(img_data)
        i += 1
    else:
        f.close()
        break `